# My ubuntu doesn't proper update

Tags: updates

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.playonlinux.com/dists/precise/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `apt` uses GPG to verify cryptographic signatures on packages that it downloads, to prevent tampering. The error sounds like you are missing key 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A from the keyring. I don't know how to manually update the keyring list though.

Comment: It looks like you are using Ubuntu 12.04. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 5):

You should add "playonlinux" repository's public key:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

after that run :

```
sudo apt update
```

from [playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) download page.